# API design using Flask, combining SQL Alchemy and Marshmallow

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, marshmallow

I am creating a simple CRUD application. I am using Flask and I've decided to use SQLAlchemy as ORM, and Marshmallow for validation of payloads.

My problem currently is to minimise the amount of replication that I need to write.

In this case, we are simply dealing with Posts.

## Create

**models.py**

```
class Post(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'posts'

    id = Column(UUID(as_uuid=True), primary_key=True)
    user_id = Column(UUID(as_uuid=True), ForeignKey('users.id'))
    title = Column(String(length=50))
```

**schemas.py**

```
class CreatePostSchema(Schema):
    title = fields.Str(required=True)
```

I do not need `id` and `user_id` as they will be created/found by the backend, but all other fields are required.

I am using BluePrints, and one of the routes/endpoints associated with post creation will have a `post()` method.

I can create decorators to first ensure the schema was correct, get the user and pass them onto the post method:

```
@auth_required()
@validate_schema(CreatePostSchema)
def post(request, user_id, cleaned_schema):
    create_post(cleaned_schema)
    return 200
```

Now, I'm able to write the `create_post()` function without hardcoding keys like:

```
def create_post(user_id, **clean_data)
    post = models.Post(**clean_data)
    post.user_id = user_id
```

But is it good practice? Or should I explicitly state the keys like:

```
def create_post(user_id, title)
    post = models.Post(title=title)
    post.user_id = user_id
    post.id = uuid4()
    return post
```

Then I also have a question at which stage to do the validation. Should validation happen before the `post()` method, or during the creation of the post? For example I could do something like:

```
def create_post(user_id, **data):
    clean_data = CreatePostSchema.load(**data)
    post = models.Post(**clean_data)
    session.add(post)
    session.commit()
    return
```

This way I can remove the additional `@has_schema()` decorator.

## Update

Update is a different beast to write without repeating keys. Let's assume we only have 1 field and `EditPostSchema = CreatePostSchema`. In reality, I will have more e.g. created date, updated date, description etc.

```
clean_data = EditPostSchema.load(**data)
id = clean_data.pop('id')
update_post(id, clean_data)

def update_post(id, **clean_data):
    session.query(Post).get(id).update(**clean_data, synchronize_session=False)
    return
```

So in essence, I am thinking that the `Schemas` should already explain the fields I need for CRUD, so that there is no need for me to repeat them. Am I correct?

Answer (score 1):

You could use [webargs](https://webargs.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) to validate input data with marshmallow schemas.

If you want to avoid code duplication, you can also try [marshmallow-sqlalchemy](https://marshmallow-sqlalchemy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) to generate API schemas from the model.

If the API is close enough to the model, you can ideed create the object by passing input data in a POST:

```
post = models.Post(**data)
```

Updates are indeed different. Some people just update the object with incoming data, but this may not work in all cases since an empty field in data should result in a deleted field in the object.

You can harcode the fields you want to update.

In an application of mine, I created a function that takes the schema as argument and uses it to know which fields are expected and update the object with incoming data, including deleting fields missing from that data.